# Mysql update value wildcard

Tags: mysql

What I am trying to do is search a whole database(small) and replace a url with another.

IE: Find url1 anywhere %url1% and update it with url2. The data on both sides of the url has to stay exactly intact.

(UPDATE * WHERE wildcard_value = %url1% with url2)

I have tried everything I know to try to update this, it needs to be ran via phpmyadmin.

Comment: To clarify, you want to check every column in every table in your database, and replace `URL1` with `URL2`, correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't know what columns your data is in, then run away now.

If you do know where the data is then it's trivial:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET url = REPLACE(url, 'www.oldsite.com', 'www.newsite.com')
WHERE url LIKE '%www.oldsite.com%';
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
update mytable set url=(select replace(url, 'someurl', 'another url') from mytable)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a mysqldump, search and replace on a text file and reimport?

- `mysqldump -u username -ppassword database_name > dump.sql`
- search and replace in your text editor of choice
- `mysql -u username -ppassword database_name < dump.sql`

This can be done through phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
UPDATE [table]
SET [column] = REPLACE([column], '/foo/', '/bar/')
```